# OPTIMIZE table and ANALYZE table MySQL 5.6 for query performance

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6

There are lot of questions/answers on this site related to `optimize table` and `analyze table.`

**Question**:If we want to do DDL/DML/SELECT fast, without thinking space even if we have fragmentation on table, can we do only `analyze table` command. because we have 500GB size table and storage engine is `innodb` it's taking time to `optimize table` command.

As per MySQL Documentation, [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html) and [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html)

1. `Optimize table` reorganizes the physical storage of table data and associated index data, to reduce storage space and improve I/O efficiency when accessing the table.
2. `Analyze table` performs a key distribution analysis and stores the distribution for the named table or tables

I think, Table stats is up to date no need to optimize table if we are not concern about space used by empty block.

Answer (score 5):

Correct. OPTIMIZE TABLE copies the data to a new tablespace, and rebuilds indexes. This takes a long time for a large table.

Defragmenting an InnoDB table doesn't improve performance much, since internally the pages are typically stored out of order regardless. That is, for InnoDB to return the "next row," it may have to follow a pointer from the current page to another page, which might be physically far away from the current page. Since this is the normal behavior of InnoDB in a non-fragmented tablespace, it might not make any difference if the pages in between are occupied or blank.

It might help to defragment a tablespace if it results in more efficiently packed pages, so the pages cached in the buffer pool represent a greater subset of the rows and indexes for the table.

Analyze table doesn't take a long time, and doesn't take *longer* for a large table. It reads a fixed number of pages as a sample of the table, and estimates index cardinality and average row size and some other stats based on this. By default, this samples 8 or 20 pages, depending on whether persistent stats are enabled.

The way analyze table helps performance is that it updates statistics that the optimizer uses to choose indexes for a given query. If the updated statistics don't make any material difference to the choice of index, it won't have any effect on performance. It only matters if the new statistics would result in the optimizer choosing a more favorable index.